# Cannot use my_module.New (type func() (*my_module.MyModule, error)) as type func() (core.Module, error) in map value

Tags: go

In my program I have an interface called `core.Module` and a struct which implements this interface called `my_module.MyModule`. Functions creating  those structs implementing my interface are added to a map in order to call them by name later:

```
type moduleConstructor func() (core.Module, error)

constructors := make(map[string]moduleConstructor)
constructors["name"] = my_module.New
```

Unfortunately the only way to make this work is to create a following `New` function:

```
func New() (core.Module, error) {
}
```

I would very much prefer to use a recommended signature:

```
func New() (*my_module.MyModule, error) {
}
```

However that causes the following error:

```
cannot use my_module.New (type func() (*my_module.MyModule, error)) as type 
func() (core.Module, error) in map value
```

Is it possible to somehow make the map accept functions which return structs implementing an interface instead of directly returning that interface?

Comment: Definitely, your two `New` functions have different types. If you want to use some methods which only defined in 'my_module.MyModule', why don't you change `moduleConstructor` to make it return a pointer to `my_module.MyModule` ?

Comment: Because there are many structs implementing this interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple anonymous function to form compliant function signature for your map without changing `my_module.New` definition. The anonymous function still call `my_module.New` in its body:

```
constructors["name"] = func New() (core.Module, error) {
    return my_module.New()
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, and since I am not getting a lot of answers something is telling me that this is the only realistic way of doing this.